# SMACK connectionClosedOnError occurs when WiFi is changed. How to handle reconnection

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I and working on a Chat Application using SMACK 4.1.7.

I receive connectionClosedOnError when Wifi is changed from A to B and I get Network Change Event through broadcast receiver.

I need to figure out how to handle this to keep connection active with server.

Comment: make it service over their and check connected or not.Please take a reference from here https://github.com/saveendhiman/XMPPSample_Studio

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the smack ReconnectionManager for handling automatic reconnect after the network switches.

http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/4.1.7/javadoc/

Smack's ReconnectionManager takes care of handling the reconnect anytime your connection is dropped unexpectedly.

You might also want to check this post

https://ramzandroidarchive.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/handling-connection-break-issue-in-smack-4-1/

It gives a good explanation on how to maintain a persistent connection.